# RxJS CombineAll() detailed explanation

Tags: rxjs

Just started learning RxJS. Really confused about the `combineAll` operator. Would really appreciate an explanation on this example code:

```
// emit every 1s, take 2
const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(2));
// map each emitted value from source to interval observable that takes 5 values
const example$ = source$.pipe(
  map(val =>
    interval(1000).pipe(
      map(i => `Result (${val}): ${i}`),
      take(5)
    )
  )
);
/*
  2 values from source will map to 2 (inner) interval observables that emit every 1s.
  combineAll uses combineLatest strategy, emitting the last value from each
  whenever either observable emits a value
*/
example$
  .pipe(combineAll())
  /*
  output:
  ["Result (0): 0", "Result (1): 0"]
  ["Result (0): 1", "Result (1): 0"]
  ["Result (0): 1", "Result (1): 1"]
  ["Result (0): 2", "Result (1): 1"]
  ["Result (0): 2", "Result (1): 2"]
  ["Result (0): 3", "Result (1): 2"]
  ["Result (0): 3", "Result (1): 3"]
  ["Result (0): 4", "Result (1): 3"]
  ["Result (0): 4", "Result (1): 4"]
*/
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

The explanation at [learnRxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combineall)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181884/rxjs-combineall-operator-explanation) StackOverflow question are not getting to my head that well.

Areas of ambiguity:

1. Why does first output show:  **["Result (0): 0", "Result (1): 0"]** instead of  **["Result (0): 0"]**

Because in the First 1000ms, "1" should not have been emitted from the source right?.

2. Why are we getting values like:
   ["Result (0): **1**", "Result (1): **0**"]

Shoulnt it be.. ["Result (0): **1**", "Result (1): **1**"]

3. According to the definition of combineAll, "Flattens an Observable-of-Observables by applying combineLatest when the Observable-of-Observables completes"

I dont really understand how it "Flattens" and Why we receive the output as individual array in 9 installments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your assumption would be correct, but there is one catch with `combineAll`. This is from the docs: **"Once the outer Observable completes, it subscribes to all collected Observables"**. This means that, `const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(2));` has to complete in order to make `combineAll` subscribe to the inner Observables. Due to `take(2)` it completes in one second with values 0 and 1. See [the doc for the combineAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineAll)

---

To answer second and third questions of yours let me describe the situation:

First of all lets mention few important notes.

1. What's the type of example$? Let's look at this bit of code `const example$ = source$.pipe(map(val => ...))`. `source$` is `Obsevable<number>` due to the `interval`. This means that when we map the value emitted by the source Observable to the new `interval` we are going to have Observable of Observables. Thus the type of `example$` is `Obsevable<Observable<number>>`. We don't want to subscribe to this type, because in that case we will receive the `Observable<number>` in the subscribe and its not what we want. That's where `combineAll` comes handy, it flattens `Obsevable<Observable<number>>` to `Observable<number>`, that's what flattening means in terms of types.
2. Now let's look at this situation in the different perspective. `combineAll` essentially is same as the `combineLatest`. Lets explain the resulted behavior in terms of `combineLatest`.

`const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(2));`, source Observable emits 2 items and completes. We are mapping this 2 events to the 2 inner Observables. In summary, we have 2 inner Observables, lets name them `inner0$` and `inner1$`.

As for comparison this is where `combineLatest` comes in. This is how we would write same code with `combineLatest`.

```
combineLatest([inner0$, inner1$])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

**Finally, whenever either of the inner0$ or inner1$ emits we get the console.log** (*Note: at the beginning both Observables should emit at least 1 value, otherwise combineLatest won't emit anything*)

Both inner stream are essentially the same, so let's visualize the streams and the console logs for the `combineLatest`

---- = 1 second

`inner0$: 0----1----2----3----4`

`inner1$: 0----1----2----3----4`

`combineLatest: [0,0]----[1,0][1,1]----[2,1][2,2]----[3,2][3,3]----[4,3][4,4]`

Comment: I can finally understand it, Thanks @Goga. One follow up question, as inner0$ was created before inner1$, that is why it is emitting first right? Does this mean that the output can not always be guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: @RahulRathod You are correct, inner0$ was created before inner1$, but it is up to `combineLatest` how to handle the subscription to inner Observables. We provide two essentially the same inner Observables to the `combineLatest` and it's going to subscribe to both of them "same time", however I guess that it will subscribe to the inner0$ first and the inner1$ second. That's why we get the order as is right now. As a final note, if there is a network call which will give us response at different times then the order of console.log will be different